# How to overwrite the whole ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to know how to overwrite the whole ArrayList in Java. With my example below, its adding with 
  `=`  a new List at the end. but i want to overwrite the whole list, after a second loop. How to do 
  this?

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList();
    Object2 object2 = new Object2();

    while(object2.checkList(list) == false) {
        list= object2.generateList(list);
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what exactly you are asking. Also the code really doesn't make a while lot of sense as it uses functions that aren't included and can only leave us guessing what they are supposed to do as well as obvious errors as `Object2 object2 = new Object();` which will not even compile.

Comment: You're replacing the entire list at every single iteration. Also, there's no reason to explicitly compare to `true` or `false` - in fact, doing so is generally considered poor style.

Comment: @Abra yes sorry, it should be Object2. So, i will try to explain it again. generateList returns me a list. But if my list doesn't match the rules. it generates me another List. But it ends with an infinite loop. So i debug through my code and discovered that the list = doesn't replace the list. Its adding it at the end. So i wanted to know, how to replace all values of a list. like overwrite.

Comment: Have you considered using method [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--) ?

Comment: list is a list of Object.  Do you really intend to have an Object2 search this list for something?  Recommendation: make sure you understand the problem you are trying to solve before writing any code.  Do your data type analysis (like doing units analysis in physics).  In your case, what is the relationship between an Object2 and any other Object you are putting into your list?  What are you checking for?  What are you generating? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As per the java docs: [List.set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-)

```
set
public E set(int index, E element)
```

It Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

So you can use :

```
  list.set( yourIndex, yourItem );
```

Comment: I know, but i don't want to the replace an element. I want to overwrite the whole list

Comment: you might need to loop through each index and replace the values